# insert into select with jpa error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, weblogic

I'm trying to do an insert into select with Jpa.
The Entity on which I try to do it is like this:

```
@Entity
public class A {
     private String fieldOne;
     private String fieldTwo;
     private String fieldThree;
     private B fieldFour;

     @Id
     public String getFieldOne(){...}
     @Id
     public String getFieldTwo(){...}
     @Id
     @OneToOne
     public B getFieldThree(){...}

     public String getFieldFour(){...}
     ....


@Entity
public class B {
    private CompositeId id;
    ....

    @EmbeddedId
    public CompositeId getId(){
        return MyUUIDGenerator.generateCompositeId();
    }
    ....
```

The insert I'm trying to is very simple:

```
insert into A (fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree, fieldFour) 
    select 'staticValueOne', 'staticValueTwo', B.id, 'staticValueFour' from B
    where ....
```

The 'staticValueX' are values calculated by the application that I need to be all equals for a given set of B elements.

During execution the application return the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: can
>   only generate ids as part of bulk insert with either sequence or
>   post-insert style generators [insert into ...

I don't understand why, because I don't have any generated value in A, I give to the insert all the values it need.
Does anyone has a suggestion to understand this behaviour?

Thanks!

**EDIT: a little update...**

I changed the class A with only a field of String type marked as @Id, but hibernate makes errors in building correctly the query: the association of tables alias with fields name miss some fields.

Comment: jpa does not support insert statement in jpa, only select, update and delete. to persist data you need to use the entitymanager and object style.

Comment: Are you executing that insert as a native query?  Because IMO you're mixing JPA and SQL in a way that's not really needed, and that makes things complicated.  Also, you should only apply @Id to [field of certain types](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html)

Comment: I'm using Jpql, no native query. I was forced to use this type of insert because of performance problems. I've also tried for test to remove all the Id, added a field with EmbeddedId using in the insert the same value of B.id and the insert worked perfectly. But I can't use this workaround.

Comment: There is no INSERT in JPQL...  Try to stick to either SQL (and in that case, drop JPA) or JPQL, mixing them can be quite hard as you will have noticed.  If you have performance problems have a look at the Hibernate query log and run analyze on the slow queries on your dbserver to understand why the query is slow, 9/10 it will just be a missing index.

Answer (score 1):

From ***JPA 2.0 specification***, chapter ***4.2 Statement Types***:

> A Java Persistence query language statement may be either a select
>   statement, an update statement, or a delete statement. (...)
>
> In BNF syntax, a query language statement is defined as:
>
> *QL_statement :: = select_statement | update_statement | delete_statement*

Instead of SELECT statement which is not supported in JPA (either in JPQL or Criteria API) use `ElementManager.persist` on an entity within a transaction. When transaction commits the entity is written to the database (SQL INSERT will be done implicitly by Hibernate which acts as the persistence provider).

EDIT: In case of a large number of insertions you may take a closer look at Hibernate's *batch inserts*. Another option is to give up with JPA and use JDBC's batch insertion (`PreparedStatement`) directly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the persist, because it is too slow: it takes about 4 seconds to store 2000 records and this query on production will work on bulk of 2/3 millions of records. So I need to find a workaround and the only idea I've found was to use the insert into select.

Comment: I've found this documentation also in Hibernate: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2610 and, if I'm not wrong, it seems to support the insert into select even if it effectively does not work